# PHP stop system() from outputting

Tags: php, apache

I have a system() query that output's ping info, how would I stop it from doing that?

```
system('ping -c1 -w1 '.$addr, $return);
```

Comment: system() is designed specifically to output. Please read the manual. http://php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php gives an overview of different functions to execute programs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://www.php.net/exec

- system(): Execute an external program and display the output
- exec(): Execute an external program
- shell_exec(): Execute command via shell and return the complete output as a string

use exec(), it doesn't output the result from the call. Or if you want the output in a string, shell_exec().

Answer (score 1):

How about trying the backtick operator? http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php

```
<?php
$output = `ls -al`;
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

This will output it into a string for you to do with as you see fit.